# Constructing the matrix representing a linear transformation given in an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a homework problem for my linear algebra class:

> Define $T: \mathcal{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_3$ by $$(T(f))(t) = 2f(t)+(1-t)f^\prime(t).$$
>   Give the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the "standard basis" $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$.

I know how to give $[T]_{stand}$ when $T$ is given as a matrix, but I'm not really sure what to do here. I thought that I should construct a set of equations, but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do with the basis. I thought that since it's mapping from $\mathcal{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_3$, the equations would look something like this. It feels very wrong because I'm not using the equation, but I'm not sure how to. 
\begin{align} T(1) &= 1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot t + 0 \cdot t^2 + 0 \cdot t^3 \\
T(t) &= t = 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot t + 0 \cdot t^2 + 0 \cdot t^3 \\
T(t^2) &= t^2 = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot t + 1 \cdot t^2 + 0 \cdot t^3 \\
T(t^3) &= t^3 = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot t + 0 \cdot t^2 + 1 \cdot t^3 \end{align}

Comment: You have everything pretty much. You just need to put the coefficients of $1,t,t^2,t^3$ of $T(1)$ into first column of your matrix, coefficients of $1,t,t^2,t^3$ of $T(t)$ into second column of your matrix, and so on.

Comment: Substitute each base function as f(t) to generate a transformed functions. You have four such function, each of those function is linear combination of the base functions. The matrix just collect all the relations in one place.